# What is meant by subset under the reflexive and transitive closure?

Tags: type-theory

I am reading through Java Language Specification SE 7, in the paragraph 4.5.1 there is a phrase as follows:

> A type argument T<sub>1</sub> is said to contain another type argument T<sub>2</sub>,
>   written T<sub>2</sub> <= T<sub>1</sub>, if the set of types denoted by T<sub>2</sub> is provably a
>   subset of the set of types denoted by T<sub>1</sub> under the reflexive and
>   transitive closure of the following rules (where <: denotes subtyping
>   (§4.10)):
>
> - ? extends T <= ? extends S if T <: S
> - ? super T <= ? super S if S <: T
> - T <= T
> - T <= ? extends T
> - T <= ? super T

I understand that there is the reflexive and transitive closure of the rules and do not understand what T<sub>2</sub> is provably a subset of the T<sub>1</sub> set *under* that closure means. Could anyone explain me that? Any references (books/papers) will be very appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather badly written. I believe that what they mean is:

> A type argument $T_1$ is said to contain another type argument $T_2$
> if $T_2\le T_1$, where $\le$ is the reflexive and
> transitive closure of the following rules (where <: denotes subtyping
> (§4.10)):
>
> - ? extends $T$ $\le$ ? extends $S$ if $T$ <: $S$
> - ? super $T$ $\le$ ? super $S$ if $S$ <: $T$
> - $T\le T$
> - $T$ $\le$ ? extends $T$
> - $T$ $\le$ ? super $T$
>
> If $T_2\le T_1$, the set of types denoted by $T_2$ is provably a
> subset of the set of types denoted by $T_1$.

(Or perhaps one could replace "if" by "if and only if" in the last line.)

(By the way, "reflexive" and the rule $T\le T$ are redundant.)